# a better way to add for each row some elements?

Tags: c, arrays

I have an array with zeros. I want to insert some elements and specifically for every row add 2 elements.

I thought doing it as below:

Let's say that I have a 3x3 array of zeros. I am using the 2d array as 1d.

If I write down as row major order I have:

```
index :          0  1  2   3  4  5   6  7  8
elements:        0  0  0 | 0  0  0 | 0  0  0
```

So, I am increasing index by i+2.

So, I did this:

```
for (int i=0;i<rows;i++){
    for (int j=0;j<col;j++){
        int count=0;
        for (int ind=0;ind<rows*col;ind++){

            A[ind]=(double)(rand()%10+1.);
            count++;

            if (count==2){
                ind+=i+col; 
                count=0;
            }
        }
     }
  }
```

1. Is there a better way to do this without using vectors or similar?
2. Also, right now I am adding elements at specific positions. Is there a way to add them at randomly positions without using "shuffle" and similar, or no way?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking.  You say 'insert some elements'; does that mean that your array that originally contained 9 elements should contain 10 after you've inserted one element?  If so, you need dynamic allocation.  I'm not clear what your code is trying to do, but a triply nested loop for a 2D array seems unlikely to be correct.  For a 3x3 array, adding 2 to an index isn't the obvious answer, either.  Please try to explain what you have and what you want.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler:Hello, my array will still contain 9 elements.Just ,for each row I will replace 2 zeros with 2 elements.Also,I want to place the elements in random places inside row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a[3][3] = { 0 };
    int *A = &a[0][0];
    int row, col;
    int i,j;
    row = col = 3;

    for(i = 0; i<row; ++i){
        int pos = rand() % col;
        for(j = 0; j< col ;++j){
            if(j != pos)
                a[i][j] = rand()%10 + 1;
        }
    }
    for(i = 0;i<row*col;++i)
        printf("%d ", A[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void swap(int *a, int *b){
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

void selectPos(int range, int num, int pos[num]){
    int i, position[range];
    for(i=0;i<range;++i){
        position[i]=i;
    }

    for(i=0;i<num;++i){
        int n = rand()%range;
        pos[i] = position[n];
        swap(&position[--range], &position[n]);
    }
}

int main(){
    int a[3][5] = { 0 };
    int *A = &a[0][0];
    int row, col;
    int i,j;
    row = 3;
    col = 5;
    srand(time(NULL));

    for(i = 0; i<row; ++i){
        int pos[3];//Determine the position this 3 out of 5
        selectPos(col, 3, pos);
        for(j = 0; j< 3 ;++j){
            a[i][pos[j]] = rand()%10 + 1;
        }
    }
    for(i = 0;i<row*col;++i)
        printf("%d ", A[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: :Hello,that's what I wanted.But I can't figure how to make it more general.For example,if I want to add only 1 element for each row,I used  "if (j!=pos && (j-1)!=pos && (j+1)!=pos)" but it doesn't work.(and also I use j-1 which can't happen).Is there a way to make it work like that?For example I want to add 3 elements or 4 elements at each row etc.Thanks!

Comment: @George, `add only 1 element` `j == pos`. 3 : all, 4 : over.

Comment: :Ok,that works but I mean more general,can I have a value for the number of elements I want to add to each row?

Comment: @George I think it can be of course. But I suppose It was not a question like that.

Comment: :In my 2nd question I say " I am adding elements at specific positions. Is there a way..."? :) .Anyway ,I thought of something if you can help.If we create a variable N which stores the number of elements I want to add to each row and use something like:int pos[N] and pos=rand()%N  but instead of taking one value for pos ,we must take N values and then checj=king the condition if (j==pos) (but pos will have N values)

Comment: :If you have an idea please let me know.:)

Comment: @George Can be complicated if a little generic, but you can of course. wait update.

Comment: @George I have added to the answer.

Comment: :Excellent!Thanks a lot!What I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

Oh! You have way too many loops. For your technique, it would be enough to have the inner loop and update (or correct) the additional increase when `count == 2` to just `ind++`. This will always initialise the first two elements in a row and leave the third unchanged.

Of course you can initialise 2 random values in a row. Start with an all-zeros matrix. Then loop over each row. Pick a random column from `0, 1, 2` and set its value. Next, pick again until the column you picked is non-zero. Set the value at that column. This works, because your random values are always different from zero.

Of course, you have to index your array like `i * col + j`. (As an aside: If you have two similar variables in your code and one is called `rows`, don't call the other one just `col` .- that's confusing.)

Answer (score 0):

First, perhaps you should define a 3x3 array:  int A[3][3];

But in the event you really just want a single dim array:  int A[9];
You can certainly define a set of rules (by the way you access and write to it) in your code such that it is treated as a 3x3.  But all you really need to do to populate is:

```
int i, A[9];
srand(clock());
for(i=0;i<sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]);i++)
{
     A[i] = rand();//using integers here, you can change it back to double       
}
```

If, for some reason you want to increment by two, change the for loop line to read:

```
for(i=0;i<sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]);i+=2)
```